# Apache Virtualhost Redirect Not Working

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I have two simple redirects set up in my virtualhost for a subdomain; one is working, one is not:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName subdomain.site.com
 Redirect / https://subdomain.site.com/subdirectory/login.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
 ServerName subdomain.site.com
 Redirect / https://subdomain.site.com/subdirectory/login.php
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/subdomain.site.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/subdomain.site.com.key
 ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
 CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The first redirect is working.  That is, if someone simply types in subdomain.site.com in their browser it redirects to https and to the correct subdirectory.  The second redirect is not working.  If someone types in https://subdomain.site.com it says "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" and the browser URL becomes "subdomain.site.com/subdirectory/login.phpsubdirectory/login.phpsubdirectory/login.phpsubdirectory/login.php..." instead of redirecting to the correct https://subdomain.site.com/subdirectory/login.php page.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I updated the above VirtualHosts file to the newer version and the problem has changed so I updated the problem description as well.

Comment: Do you really need a Redirect if `https` scheme is used ? Do a SSL handshake and server the web pages when port is `443`. Just curious.

Comment: Is that full `<VirtualHost>` block? There should be few more lines: SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt

Comment: So the rest of the SSLEngine codeblock was in a separate ssl.conf file in the conf.d directory.  I moved these entries to the same site.conf file and ended up breaking everything.  Trying again.

Comment: you are doing a redirect in both http to https and https to https it will redirect infinetly, you shouldn't do the redirect from the 443 config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, none of the answers above worked so I had to keep working on this.  Ultimately I removed the redirect line from the :443 virtualhost section and added the following two lines to the same section to get this to work correctly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ https://subdomain.site.com/subdirectory/login.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday, for me it worked to add this line:
127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this line to top of file

NameVirtualHost x.x.x.x:443 or domaine name:443

check you apache version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to top of file :

```
NameVirtualHost x.x.x.x
```

and

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work and actually broke the existing setup.

    Starting httpd: [Wed Dec 24 09:33:15 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.1:0 has no VirtualHosts
    (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
    (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

Comment: change 192.168.1.1 to your ip address or just try to these lines : 

`Listen 80`
`Listen 443`

Comment: I just typed in 192.168.1.1 here for consistency sake; on my webserver I used the actual webserver eth0 internal IP.  I also tried removing the NameVirtualHost line with just the listen lines and it also didn't work.  Right now I'm suspecting whoever set up the self signed SSL cert here didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on ubuntu (I mean debian based linux distro)in your /etc/hosts you should define a line like below :
127.0.0.1    yourdomain

and then in make a new file for your new site configuration in :
/etc/apache2/sites-available/

and name it like your domain name .conf just to don't forget what is that conf file for.
then enable new conf with following command 
a2ensite your_conf_name
then restart apache.
now your new site configuration is ready.
now look at following link :
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html
you have to mention that your apache should listen on multiple port 
in your case 80 , 443

Comment: I'm on CentOS 6.5, but I still tried modifying the hosts file and restarting and it didn't work.  Thanks though.

Comment: FYI, its 127.0.0.1 (you forgot the 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSL you should change default-ssl.conf settings like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.site.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.site.com  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.site.com
```